# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 178175077: invalid start byte

Tags: python, git, utf-8, decoding, gitpython

I am trying to encode gerrit uid's to utf-8 and running into below error,it works most of time but randomly running into below error for some uid's,I have looked at similar posts on stackoverflow which suggest to ry ISO-8859-1 but utf-8 works most time for me,how to fix it?

```
uid = Ia7324f6443b3db5d55113a221dc0791bb5a38799
uID = gerritInfo['id'].encode("utf-8")
```

Error stack:-

```
 result=main()
  File "/prj/team/location/script", line 1363, in main
    (picked_gerrit,uID,email_state) = cherrypick_gerrit(buildDir,manifest,gerrit,patch,False,errorLog,picklogfd)
  File "/prj/team/location/script", line 356, in cherrypick_gerrit
    if uID in repo.git.log():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 450, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 902, in _call_process
    return self.execute(make_call(), **_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 698, in execute
    stdout_value = stdout_value.decode(defenc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 178175077: invalid start byte
```

Comment: The stacktrace is not related to the lines of code you posted.

Comment: why do you say so? it is failing at `uID in repo.git.log():` `repo.git.log()` is a python module `http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html` and I provided a example of an uID that fails

Comment: The stack trace indicates a ***decoding*** error. 0xf6 is not valid as a standalone byte or start of a multi byte character.  Show us /prj/team/location/script around line 1363.

Comment: line 1363 looks like `for gerritPatch in eCRMgerritList:

      (gerrit, sep, patch) = gerritPatch.partition(r'/')
      (picked_gerrit,uID,email_state) = cherrypick_gerrit(buildDir,manifest,gerrit,patch,False,errorLog,picklogfd)`

Comment: I am totally clueless on how to debug on why `if uID in repo.git.log():` would throw such an error,really appreciate any help or pointers to DEBUG

Comment: where **`\r`** or any special character? Perhaps divide header, change server answer, bad joke !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/237 ,you can try something like below,use stdout_as_string=False

```
if uID in repo.git.log(stdout_as_string=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

add  `# coding=utf-8`   to first line of the python file.

Comment: Jerry - how does that help? I am already doing `uID = gerritInfo['id'].encode("utf-8")`

Comment: execute  print(gerritInfo['id'])   what is the result

Comment: `Ia7324f6443b3db5d55113a221dc0791bb5a38799` is the result,are you expecting to see any special characters?

Comment: the result of  gerritInfo['id'] maybe a object  not a string type

try convert it to string  with str(gerritInfo['id']).encode("utf-8")